# Validate TLS 1.2 on AAD Connect server

Tags: azure-active-directory, tls1.2

I have upgraded AAD Connect to the latest version and made the registry changes according to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/hybrid/reference-connect-tls-enforcement, but is there a way to validate that I am actually using TLS 1.2?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to do a network capture and validate that just TLSv1.2 is being used.